# CSS hover effect not working on Firefox…

Tags: css

I have some markers over the top of a map and the goal is to have a hover effect over each marker to show additional information. I used an ID for the image and the following CSS:

```
#pan {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

#pan:hover:before {
  content: url('http://devmg.redtogreendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/PAN_Hover.png') no-repeat !important;
  display: block;
  position: absolute!important;
  top: 50px;
  right: -200px!important;
  z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

Works great in safari! However, nothing happens in Firefox. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a Tip. Stackoverflow has a special script area. Just hit one times enter and than 4 spaces. Everything with the 4 spaces will be placed in a script area so it looks nicer.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: First of, what's up with all the `!important`. Try to refrain from using them. Secondly, it is better practice to define the pseudo `:before` without the hover, but only toggle the pseudo element on hover (i.e. its display property).

Comment: Check my answer with DEMO. It's working now in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `no-repeat` inside `content` property. By specification `no-repeat` is not valid `content` property value.
If you want more image control use `background` property. Because of images or gradients inserted using `content` cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using `no-repeat` on a `content` property. Just remove it.

```
#pan:hover:before {
    content: url('http://devmg.redtogreendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/PAN_Hover.png') !important;
    display: block;
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 50px;
    right: -200px!important;
    z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/gw87ndfr/1/)**